# Can I prevent third party apps from using Diskpart – Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, security, diskpart

I have  Windows 7 64 bit (EFI Mode boot) desktop PC. As the title suggests, I would like to know if there’s any way I can prevent third party apps from accessing diskpart.exe on my system.

I generally login with a single username that is Administrator on my PC. I find that sometimes  third party apps like for example Truecrypt try to use diskpart if it finds that say a  pen drive volume being encrypted and to be mounted is read only.

If that’s not possible, is it safe to rename or delete diskpart.exe from the  system32 / syswow64 folders?

Will it cause any damage to Windows 7 installation in anyway like boot failure, crash/hang, BSOD or would it impact any other apps like for example Admin Tools-Disk Management Console or so?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it is using diskpart? Because it is not that hard to program the capabilities of diskpart into you program. So disabling access to it does not automatically mean they can't use the functionality that diskpart does. But the easiest way is to just rename the program.

Comment: diskpart.exe is useless on its own. The real work is done by the disk manager service.

Comment: TrueCrypt doesn’t support GPT or UEFI (obviously you don’t have FDE enabled if you are using TrueCrypt)

Comment: @LPChip, Yes Truecrypt does use Diskpart. You can test it using a TC encrypted pendrive  that's set set as ReadOnly thru Diskpart. TC runs Diskpart and removes the ReadOnly protection. TC however fails to remove ReadOnly protection  if the underlying service named Virtual Disk is Stopped & Disabled.After going thru above comments, I shall refine my question with a different perspective. Thanks.